# How to parse feedburner xml and display on site using google feed API

Tags: xml, wordpress, parsing, feed, google-feed-api

I have a feed coming from Wordpress and flowing through Feedburner. I would like to take the feed from Feedburner and display node values on my website like such:

Title
Description
Audio Link
Comment Count ()

Will the google feed API allow me to grab the media encosure url??? or is it limited to what you can grab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to first create a custom feed and feed template from WordPress since this is the source of any feed burned by Feedburner.

To get it done please see the following article that walks you through the whole process, "[How to Create a Custom RSS Feed in WordPress in 12 Lines of Code](http://www.seodenver.com/custom-rss-feed-in-wordpress/)".

Once you've followed the article simply burn a new feed and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If it's part of the XML feed, then you can grab it and show it on your website.

Can you paste a sample of the xml source from the feed here? That will tell all. (One way of doing this is to open the feed url in ie... it usually shows the source)